# Dummy-coded predictor in mediation analysis with psych::mediate in R

Tags: r, mediation

I have a question regarding the correlation between dummy-coded predictors in mediation analysis with `psych::mediate` in R.

I have 3 categorical conditions for my predictor. The results showed me a standardized correlation of -0.5 between the dummy-coded predictors, which makes sense if you calculate correlations between  `0 1 0 0 1 0 ...` and `0 0 1 0 0 1 ...`.

Does that influence the results of the mediation analysis in any way, or is it just a relic that can be ignored?

My code:

```r
psych::mediate(Y ~  Dummy_2 + Dummy_3 + (Mediator), data=Data_Dummy, std = TRUE)
```

Comment: This should be fine. There's even an example with dummy variables in the documetnation for mediate.